# This code is giving me empty line layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv

This code run well but produces an empty line layer with no attribute

```
from qgis.core import QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.utils import iface

# Path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'F:/FOB Files/Python/Robo.csv'

# Name of the vector layer to be created
layer_name = 'LinesLayer'

# Create a new vector layer for lines
lines_layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', layer_name, 'memory')

# Check if the layer was created successfully
if not lines_layer.isValid():
    print('Failed to create the lines layer.')
else:
    # Add the layer to the map
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lines_layer)

    # Open the CSV file and create LineString features
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        next(file)  # Skip the header line
        for line in file:
            # Assuming the CSV file has columns 'start_Latitude', 'start_Longitude', 'end_Latitude', 'end_Longitude'
            try: 
                start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude = map(float, line.strip().split(','))
            except ValueError:
                # Skip lines with invalid coordinates
                print(f"Skipping line: {line}")
                continue

            # Create LineString geometry
            line_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(start_latitude, start_longitude), QgsPointXY(end_latitude, end_longitude)])

            # Create a feature and set its geometry
            feature = QgsFeature()
            feature.setGeometry(line_geometry)

            # Set attributes for the feature
            feature.setAttributes([start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude])

            # Add the feature to the layer
            lines_layer.addFeature(feature)

    # Refresh the map canvas to see the changes
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    print(f'Lines added to the layer "{layer_name}" in QGIS.')
```

Comment: Yes  please.

start_Latitude start_Longitude end_Latitude end_Longitude
[6.58 3.36, 6.57 3.37], [6.65 3.3, 6.66 3.29], [6.65 3.31, 6.66 3.31]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correction below. The main issue was not declaring the attributes structure. I've also switched your code order to add layer **after** adding all the features. Messed also with order of longitude, latitude in your code (you may change back the order depending of your file structure)

My `Robo.csv` file content

```
start_Latitude,start_Longitude,end_Latitude,end_Longitude
47.58471164392989,1.3404569233603354,47.160217236404065,2.309833535359644
46.18503073881979,0.8739899822481334,46.149696749646154,2.579509735690607
44.23548539634393,-0.17457536909557803,45.23732784204478,5.68151253467218
```

The code sample fixed

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.utils import iface

# Path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'F:/FOB Files/Python/Robo.csv'

# Name of the vector layer to be created
layer_name = 'LinesLayer'

# Create a new vector layer for lines
lines_layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', layer_name, 'memory')
# Set attributes for the feature
pr = lines_layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("start_latitude", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("start_longitude",  QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("end_latitude", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("end_longitude", QVariant.Double)])
lines_layer.updateFields()

# Open the CSV file and create LineString features
with open(csv_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    next(file)  # Skip the header line
    for line in file:
        # Assuming the CSV file has columns 'start_Latitude', 'start_Longitude', 'end_Latitude', 'end_Longitude'
        try: 
            start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude = map(float, line.strip().split(','))
        except ValueError:
            # Skip lines with invalid coordinates
            print(f"Skipping line: {line}")
            continue

        # Create LineString geometry
        line_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(start_longitude, start_latitude), QgsPointXY(end_longitude, end_latitude)])
        print(line_geometry, start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude)

        # Create a feature and set its geometry
        feature = QgsFeature()
        feature.setGeometry(line_geometry)

        feature.setAttributes([start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude])

        # Add the feature to the layer
        pr.addFeature(feature)

# Check if the layer was created successfully
if not lines_layer.isValid():
    print('Failed to create the lines layer.')
else:
    lines_layer.updateExtents() 
    # Add the layer to the map
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lines_layer)



# Refresh the map canvas to see the changes
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

print(f'Lines added to the layer "{layer_name}" in QGIS.')
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your contribution. 
But after running the code, the line are not plotted as expected

Comment: Updated my sample accordingly